# Does bounded upper derivative imply differentiability?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function defined on $[a,b]$ such that for any $t \in [a,b]$
$$
\limsup_{s\to t}\frac{f(s)-f(t)}{s-t} \le C_0
$$
where $C_0$ is a uniform constant. Can we conclude that $f$ is continuous or even differentiable at almost all points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the condition implies that 
$$ g(t) = C_0 t - f(t)$$
is non-decreasing on $[a,b]$. Then $g$ is differentiable a.e.
[Royden, Real Analysis, Chap 5,sec 1, Thm 3]